# Trying to build a model in sparqlML in java but getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, machine-learning, sparql

I am trying to build a ML model using sparqlML in Java but while building the query, I am getting an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main":
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/lang/sparql/TokenMgrError
```

The code that throws the exception:

```java
QueryML query = QueryFactoryML.create(queryString);
QueryExecutionML qe = QueryExecutionFactoryML.create(query, dataset);
Model trainModel = qe.execCreate();
trainModel.write(System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
```

Comment: and how did you add Jena in a version < `3.x` to your Java classpath?

Comment: I just have imported all the required jar files of jena 2.10.0 and sparqlml 0.40